# Converting Date formats in R

Tags: r, date

```
dates <- as.Date(dli$Dates)

class(dates)
[1] "Date"

dates
   [1] "2016-01-01" "2016-01-02" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-04" "2016-01-05" "2016-01-06"
   [7] "2016-01-07" "2016-01-08" "2016-01-09" "2016-01-10" "2016-01-11" "2016-01-12"
  [13] "2016-01-13" "2016-01-14" "2016-01-15" "2016-01-16" "2016-01-17" "2016-01-18"
  [19] "2016-01-19" "2016-01-20" "2016-01-21" "2016-01-22" "2016-01-23" "2016-01-24"
  [25] "2016-01-25" "2016-01-26" "2016-01-27" "2016-01-28" "2016-01-29" "2016-01-30"
  [31] "2016-01-31" "2016-02-01" "2016-02-02" "2016-02-03" "2016-02-04" "2016-02-05"
  [37] "2016-02-06" "2016-02-07" "2016-02-08" "2016-02-09" "2016-02-10" "2016-02-11"
```

This is my date format , so i need to convert it into "2016-month-day"
I am getting NA values

```
dates <- as.Date(dli$Dates,"%d/%b/%Y")

class(dates)
[1] "Date"

dates
   [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [31] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [61] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  [91] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [121] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

can you give any suggestions
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You probably need to use `"%d/%m/%Y"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To obtain your required format i.e., *2016-month-day* , you can use `format` function once you have converted vector of strings to `Date` type.

I hope below code snippet clears your doubt.

```
> d = c("2016-02-08","2016-02-18","2015-02-08","2016-02-02")
> class(d)
[1] "character"
> d = as.Date(d)
> class(d)
[1] "Date"
> d = format(d,"%Y-%b-%d")
> d
[1] "2016-Feb-08" "2016-Feb-18" "2015-Feb-08" "2016-Feb-02"
```

Format function converts the date type objects into the required format. Refer to this [link](https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html) for more information on date type formatting.

Answer (score 19):

Good practice is to store date in R as YYYY-MM-DD, and your strings already seem to be at the good format, but :

The format you're passing to `as.Date` must describe what the strings contain, not what you're expecting as an output.

`"%d/%b/%Y"` stands for "day as a number (0-31) slash  abbreviated month slash 4-digit year", and your strings format are "4-digit year - month as a number - day as a number".

If you want to format the date, you need to call `format` :

```
> date <- "2016-01-01"
> date <- as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
> date
[1] "2016-01-01"
> format(date, "%d/%b/%Y")
[1] "01/jan/2016"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to render your dates in this format, then use `format`:

```
x <- as.Date("2016-01-01")
format(x, "%Y %b %a %d")

[1] "2016 Jan Fri 01"
```

There is a separation of concerns here.  If you already have your date information stored in R as date types, then you need not change anything internally to extract further information from those dates.

### Demo

Comment: hi Tim ,    I used the above command but i got the same error  ,         
   dates<-as.Date(dli$Dates,"%Y %b %a %d")
> dates
   [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA               Actually my dates are in character form

Comment: What you ran doesn't look at all like my answer.  If you have text dates, then convert them to date type using `as.Date` first, then call format.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `as.Date()` to convert between dates saved as character and `Date` objects.

If you want to change the format of a `Date` object, you can use `format()`.
You have specified `"2016-month-day"` as the desired format of the dates in the question, but in the code you provide you are using `"%d/%b/%Y"`. The way this works is: the `%` indicates that the next character will be a conversion specification, everything else (e.g. (`-` or `/`) will be used for finding / adding delimiter to the date representation. (see `?strptime` for details).

So in your case, just use

```
dates <- format(dli$Dates, format = "%Y-%b-%d")
```

to get the result specified in the text of the question:

```
[1] "2016-Jan-01" "2016-Jan-02" "2016-Jan-03" "2016-Jan-04" "2016-Jan-05"
```

or this:

```
dates <- format(dli$Dates, format = "%Y/%b/%d")
```

to get what you have used in the code snipped:

```
[1] "2016/Jan/01" "2016/Jan/02" "2016/Jan/03" "2016/Jan/04" "2016/Jan/05"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package lubridate to convert to a date with ymd then format it for the way you want it displayed

```
Dates_df <-  mutate(Dates, dli = format(ymd(dli), "%Y/%b/%d")
```

(I use dplyr here, I assume you have other variables in Dates)

without dplyr if you just want to keep the dates in a vector:

```
Dates_vec <-  format(ymd(Dates$dli), "%Y/%b/%d")
```