# loop through dates from data

Tags: r, dplyr

Below is a sample of my data
Data

```
Buisness Year       Severity
   <chr>    <date>        <dbl>
 1 OLT      2009-06-30    44504
 2 OLT      2009-12-31    45540
 3 OLT      2010-06-30    46511
 4 OLT      2010-12-31    48479
 5 OLT      2011-06-30    48234
 6 OLT      2011-12-31    50367
 7 OLT      2012-06-30    53338
 8 OLT      2012-12-31    52777
 9 OLT      2013-06-30    51593
10 OLT      2013-12-31    54146
```

I want to loop through specific dates in my data

I tried making vector of the dates I wanted

```
date_list <- c("12-31-2009","12-31-2010",
               "12-31-2011",
               "12-31-2012",
               "12-31-2013",
               "12-31-2014",
               "12-31-2015",
               "12-31-2016",
               "12-31-2017",
               "12-31-2018")
```

Then I run the following code

```
for (value in variable_list) {
  for(value1 in date_list) {
    Data1 <- Data %>%
      filter(Buisness == "Workers Comp", Year == value1)

  }
}
```

It gives me an error because the "Year" variable is a date and "value1" is a string.

Please Help

Comment: Try `format(as.Date(date_list,'%m-%d-%Y'),'%Y')` to obtain years. Same for your original dataframe.

Comment: Have a look at  the `as.Date()` function in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680101/converting-date-formats-in-r) question please. Additionally instead of a for loop, `%in%` operator can be more useful I think.

Comment: this is the output ``` format(as.Date(date_list,'%m-%d-%Y'),'%Y')
 [1] "2009" "2010" "2011" "2012" "2013" "2014"
 [7] "2015" "2016" "2017" "2018" ```